# Does checking Cache Api, fetch API and IndexedDB API individual support check is necessary prior to serviceWorker implementation

Tags: browser, service-worker

Do we need to check each API ([Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache), [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) and [Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API)) individually support in the browser before implementing service worker or checking service worker is enough? what is the best practice?

means

```
if('Cache' in window) {}
if ('fetch' in window) {}
if('indexedDB' in window) {}
if('navigator' in window) {}
if(navigator.onLine){}
```

OR

`if('serviceWorker in navigator)`

is enough?

what did I assume that later method will internally call the former methods in order to check service worker?

Is that correct assumption?

if not then what is the default and what neede to check?

Comment: "what did I assume that later method will check fetch, push, Cache prior to checking service worker?" Can you elaborate what you mean here? if('serviceWorker in navigator) is contained in the Service Worker register file and so is seen before any of the service worker code is seen. Ie, no push/catch/fetch events will be fired before checking if the browser supports SW.

Answer (score 0):

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) is enough.

All browsers that implement the SW API also implement the Fetch, Caches and IndexedDB APIs.

There are some gotchas, though. Latest versions of Chrome and FF support async/await but for instance Samsung Internet doesn't. SI supports SW, so using async/await in the SW throws in SI.